# MySQL/PHP count number of columns that are not NULL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting a number of database columns from a MySQL database.  I would like to count the number of returned MySQL rows from a particular set that is not NULL.

For example...

```
SELECT p.wavURL1, p.wavURL2, p.wavURL3, p.wavURL4,  etc.
```

Can I count in PHP the number of these that are not `NULL`?

Comment: What do you mean by a row being NULL? Do you mean all the values in the row are NULL?

Comment: I have 16 columns that need to be counted.  I don't need them added to the count if they are NULL.  There are other columns that I do not need counted, so I can't select all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(COALESCE(col1, col2, ..., col16)) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
```

See the MySQL manual for more details:

- [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) - Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement.
- [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) - Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting this to work.  It's returning "1" as a value no matter how many columns I add.  I need it to give me the sum of the # of columns that are not NULL.

Comment: This didn't work for me either.  It appears to count the number of rows that have at least one non-null column.  The question is asking about the number of columns in each row that are not null.

Comment: By definition COALESCE returns only 1 value, so the count will always be 1.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
 if(p.wavURL1 is null,0,1)+
 if(p.wavURL2 is null,0,1)+
 if(p.wavURL3 is null,0,1)+
 if(p.wavURL4 is null,0,1) as count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a case statement for each of that returns either 1 or 0 depending on whether or not they are null.  Then you can sum the results

```
SELECT
    (
        CASE WHEN p.wavURL1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN p.wavURL2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN p.wavURL3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN p.wavURL4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    ) AS num_urls
FROM (
    SELECT 
        'a' AS wavURL1,
        'b' AS wavURL2,
        'c' AS wavURL3,
        NULL AS wavURL4
    ) AS p
;
```

This returns `num_urls` as `3` for me because there are three non-null values in the input.

Answer (score 0):

conceptually NULL means “a missing unknown value”

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalRows
FROM tableNAME
WHERE columnName IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get the count directly via issuing a SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table p WHERE 
      <someconditions> 
      AND p.wavURL1 IS NOT NULL 
      AND p.wavURL2 IS NOT NULL 
      AND p.wavURL3 IS NOT NULL  
      AND p.wavURL4 IS NOT NULL
```

Another possibility is the `coalesce` method. But there are different views on that. Performance may differ between `IS NULL` (which is not ANSI standard) and `coalesce`.

See: http://sqlserverperformance.idera.com/tsql-optimization/performance-coalesce-null/

- If performance does not matter prefer **coalesce**.
- If performance matters you need to benchmark both variants to see which outperforms the other.

If you want to count it as you state it in PHP itself. You may iterate over every row and increase a count variable by one for each iteration.

I would see the statement approach as preferable though.